# Some of my coroutines are not (always) starting

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, langchain, python-3.11

I am working with Langchain and FastApi. Basically I am creating a StreamingResponse, which streams back JSON diffs. The diffs are created by comparing a JSON document to its previous version. The various attributes of the JSON are generated by information it receives from OpenAI through langchain chains (with LCEL (https://python.langchain.com/docs/expression_language/) (also streamed).

To come up with all the attributes, I run a function called 'run' that triggers other (async) functions. These async functions add a json diff to an async.queue. The **anext** method unloads the queue.

The code is quite complex, i tried to condense the relevant parts in here:

This is the code that creates the async generator. The run method of the RunAgent actually builds the document and fills the queue.

```py
from jsonpatch import JsonPatch
import asyncio
from pydantic import BaseModel
from src.llm.chain import meta_chain, sub_object_meta_chain, sub_object_details_chain
from src.schema import MyObject


class IterableAgent(BaseModel):
    queue: asyncio.Queue | None = None
    done: bool = False
    timeout: int = 10

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.done and self.queue.empty():
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        try:
            return await asyncio.wait_for(self.queue.get(), timeout=self.timeout)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

    def __aiter__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        asyncio.create_task(self.run())
        return self

    @abstractmethod
    def run():
        raise NotImplementedError


class RunAgent(IterableAgent):
    _last_object: str = "{}"

    def _get_patch(self) -> str:
        new_object = self.object.model_dump_json()
        patch = JsonPatch.from_diff(self._last_object, new_object).patch
        self._last_object = new_object
        return patch

    def _continue_response(self) -> None:
        patch = self._get_patch()
        if patch:
            self.queue.put_nowait(patch)

    async def _add_meta(self):
        inputs = dict()  # Any inputs I need here for the chain...
        async for result in meta_chain.astream(inputs):
            self.object.meta = result
            self._continue_response()

    async def _add_sub_objects_meta(self):
        inputs = dict()  # Any inputs I need here for the chain...
        async for result in sub_object_meta_chain.astream(inputs):
            self.object.sub_objects = result
            self._continue_response()

    async def _add_sub_objects_details(self, so):
        inputs = dict(so=so)  # Any inputs I need here for the chain...
        async for result in sub_object_details_chain.astream(inputs):
            so.details = result
            self._continue_response()

    async def run(self):
        self.object = MyObject()
        await self._add_meta()
        await self._add_sub_objects_meta()
        cors = [self._add_sub_objects_details(so) for so in self.object.sub_objects]
        # I tried to create tasks instead of just having coroutines, no luck there...
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(x) for x in cors]
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        self.done = True
```

Then there is also a small piece of code in my FastApi router that uses the generator to feed into the StreamingResponse.

```py
@router.post("/new")
async def new_document(req: MyRequest):
    \# The agent is implemented to be an AsyncIterator
    agent = RunAgent() # I would typically unpack MyRequest and feed the relevant data into the  agent initialization
    return StreamingResponse(agent, media_type="application/json")
```

#### My problem

Now this works quite well, however sometimes, it just stops half way. The queue.get just times out. It seems as if tasks are just not started. It does seem that any tasks/coroutines that have started do complete. So for example What i would see for instance is the metadata of the base object gets generated, but the metadata of the subobjects not. Or the details of one of the sub objects is missing. I think there is some race condition, I just know where....

Comment: One thing I see is that `__aiter__` should never be called twice on the same `RunAgent` instance if it (as async iterator) wasn't exhausted already. The code mixes iterable and iterator which shouldn't be done.

Comment: Alright. But I don't think ```__aiter__``` is called twice. In my understanding it is called once by StreamingResponse to get the iterator on which it can call ```__anext__``` until it reaches a StopIteration.

Answer (score 2):

Python asyncio has a peculiar design choice that leads to a problem which is likely what you hit there:

Tasks created with `.create_task` are not hard-referenced by the event loop. (it keeps only a weak-reference to them). While this sometimes do not show up in straightforward runs, or when there are few tasks- as the weak-referenced tasks are actually started in the first execution of the asyncio loop core, when there are lots of tasks (~2000 in some tests I made), or possibly less, when task creation takes place in more than one place like in this code, tasks may just vanish without trace.

That is likely your problem, and the solution is simply keeping a reference to tasks created by `.create_task` calls - a simple class-level `set` can keep those (or an instance level, if you have an `__init__` method there):

```
...

class IterableAgent(BaseModel):
    queue: asyncio.Queue | None = None
    done: bool = False
    timeout: int = 10
    running_tasks: set[asyncio.Task] = set()

    ...

    def __aiter__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.run())
        self.running_tasks.add(task)
        task.add_done_callback(self.running_tasks.discard)
        return self
    
   ...
```

(of course, use the same pattern if there are other calls to `.create_task`).

As for were this behavior is documented, note the "important" note at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do this, but it did not work... I also logged the newly created running_tasks on every call to ```__anext__```, and i see them all there...

Comment: so, there is some subtle thig going on that is hard to spot just by staring at the code. If you can modify your input so that it is a stand-alone script, including the imports, that can reproduce the error, I might take a deeper look into this. (i.e.: if it becomes a minimal reproducible example, I can copy and past into my computer and see the issue, including fake data sources if needed).

Comment: One thing to try, though, if you are on Python 3.11 is to change your `.run()` method to use an asyncio.TaskGroup - instead of relying on a sole `.gather` call - sorry, but I can't come with a reason for it, but that  'TaskGroup"s should be make the tasks created inside it reliable.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried with a TaskGroup after your comment and reading the docs, no luck there either. I am suspecting Langchain of not keeping hard references to their tasks in the lcel chains that i use. But I have not had the time to dive into that yet. I will try to come up with a working example to demonstate the buggy behaviour.

Comment: great. It maybe that LangChain itself is not keeping a reference to its tasks, as you say, for the "missing task" behavior is often only triggered after several hundred created tasks, it is easy to not cover such a scenario on tests. If we can zero in that as a cause, it should be possible to create a custom event loop that will keep references to all tasks automatically.